# Dell Inspirion Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, restore, wifi-configuration

I accidentally hit Forget in regards to my network and cannot restore my WiFi, because I can't find the 8 digit PIN on my router. Is there a way to retrieve this or restore my WiFi settings prior to me hitting forget?

Comment: Do you have any other device connected to the same network ? Can you connect your computer to the router using a Ethernet and login to it ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information, such as *what model router*.

1. Look up the manual for the device online, if you do not have it.
2. Find the default password.
3. Hit the router's reset button (or other technique mentioned in the manual) to reset the password to its default.
4. Enter the password on your PC and *then change it with the router GUI interface*.
5. [Change security mode to WPA2 with AES](http://routersecurity.org/).
6. Now update the password in other devices connected to that router.